# Update checkout total on selection list change

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

How i can update the checkout total on selection list change event. I am using ajax to update the price. Code:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_my_downpay", "my_downpay");
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_downpay', 'my_downpay');

function my_downpay() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Ozdobne pudełka:', 20 );
    die();
}
```

Selection list screen short: http://prntscr.com/lay65b

Comment: You should include all your related code… Please note that: *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*. Actually your code is just not testable. Some more details and explanations are required. So please make some effort if you want to increase the chance at least to get one useful answer, as nobody can guess what is in your mind.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Can you help me that how to disable and enable payment gateway in woocommerce.

Comment: Where is your other code like the jQuery or javascript that is involved in this Ajax? Where is the code related to this select fields? What are the payment gateways that you want to disable / enable and how in details? … So Edit / update your question please. Actually your question is not answerable.